# Cannot sent cookie with Guzzle request

Tags: php, cookies, guzzle

I have a PHP script that needs to fetch a CSV file from an application. There is an API for the application that allows the script to lot in, which gives the script a session cookie for authentication. I then need to doa GET request to fetch the CSV file (which the API does not support).

Using curl directory works:

```
$c = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'PHPSESSID=' . $session_id_from_api);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$csv_file = curl_exec($c);
echo $csv_file;
```

That fetches the CSV file using the session ID obtained from the API login and passed through a coookie.

Now, I would like to do the same thing using Guzzle, but I just get the login page back instead. This is the code I'm using:

```
$client = new Guzzle\Http\Client();
$request = $client->get(
    $url,
    [
        'cookies' => ['PHPSESSID' => $session_id_from_api],
    ]
);
$response = $client->send($request);
echo $response->getBody(true);
```

That gives me the login page, so the GET to the application is not recognising the session defined by the cookie.

Is there anything else I need to do to ensure the cookie and value I specify is sent to the remote application?

Edit: looking at `$request->getRawHeaders()`, I see this line in the headers:

```
cookies: vec6nb1egvvui6op7qr7b0oqf6
```

That obviously isn't right. The documentation for my version of Guzzle gives this example:

```
// Enable cookies and send specific cookies
$client->get('/get', ['cookies' => ['foo' => 'bar']]);
```

which looks to me to be consistent with what I am passing to Guzzle.

Just to be clear, I am not trying to manage cookies in both directions over multiple requests, so there is no need to store any cookies. I have a cookie name and its value (from another source), and I just want to make sure that name and value gets sent to the destination for a single GET request. I'm not trying to "maintain a session", but in a way I am having a session passed to me from another part of the application (not Guzzle) and need to set my Guzzle request up to use it.

Comment: I'm using Guzzle 3.1.2 - maybe upgrading that will help.

Comment: Looking at Guzzle, it seems that cookie handling is some kind of plugin. Am I perhaps not invoking or enabling the plugin, so the "cookie" parameters are not being picked up and converted into the proper headers? Similarly, I'm using the "timeout" parameter, but Guzzle is blindly turning that into a header and passing it in the request, rather than using the timeout parameter as an instruction to Guzzle.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, this seems to work. Guzzle was not sending the cookie without being sure the domain it was sending it to was correct:

```
// Set up a cookie - name, value AND domain.
$cookie = new Guzzle\Plugin\Cookie\Cookie();
$cookie->setName('PHPSESSID');
$cookie->setValue($session_id_from_api);
$cookie->setDomain($domain_of_my_service_url);

// Set up a cookie jar and add the cookie to it.
$jar = new Guzzle\Plugin\Cookie\CookieJar\ArrayCookieJar();
$jar->add($cookie);

// Set up the cookie plugin, giving it the cookie jar.
$plugin = new Guzzle\Plugin\Cookie\CookiePlugin($jar);

// Register the plugin with the client.
$client->addSubscriber($plugin);

// Now do the request as normal.
$request = $client->get($url);
$response = $client->send($request);

// The returned page body.
echo $response->getBody(true);
```