# How to send cookie with Laravel Http client?

Tags: laravel, guzzle, httpcookie, laravel-http-client

I am trying to set cookies using the Laravel HTTP client. I know Laravel uses `guzzlehttp/guzzle` library in the backend.

This is the error I am getting when I try to set the cookies using `withOptions` method.
[image]

Have anyone figured it out?

Comment: [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25326646/cannot-sent-cookie-with-guzzle-request/25328483#25328483) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40998662/how-can-i-send-cookies-with-guzzlehttp-guzzle-6).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I utilized withCookies to include cookies with the request, although it's worth noting that this method isn't explicitly documented in the Laravel official documentation.

```
Http::withCookies([
    '.ASPXAUTH' => $this->authCookie,
]
```

Answer (score 0):

It says the error is on line 35 and I can't see that line but by the error my guess is you are passing the `$this->auth_cookie` as a cookie for your next request and that's why the error says `cookies must be an instance of CookieJarInterface`

the thing is when you call `$authCookie->getValue()` it returns the value of cookie which is string. If you want the `$this->auth_cookie` to be CookieJarInterface you should use this instead

```
$this->auth_cookie = $authCookie;
```

Hope it helps